# Triggering the scroll of a different dom object by scrolling on an object that doesn't need to scroll with vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a small scroll interaction that works beautifully in the elements that need to scroll. But I'd like to have the scroll behaviors of OTHER objects happen when I scroll over an object that doesn't need to scroll.

For instance, with the following code, I want the allScroll event to trigger the scrolls of the other dom objects.

```
  <script>
    var isSyncingTopScroll = false;
    var isSyncingBottomScroll = false;
    var isSyncingLogoScroll = false;
    var topPhrase = document.getElementById('top-phrase');
    var bottomPhrase = document.getElementById('bottom-phrase');
    var logo = document.getElementById('logo');
    var allScroll = document.getElementById('scroll-landing');

    allScroll.onscroll = function() {
      if (!isSyncingTopScroll || !isSyncingBottomScroll || !isSyncingLogoScroll) {
        isSyncingTopScroll = true;
        isSyncingBottomScroll = true;
        isSyncingLogoScroll = true;
        topPhrase.scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
        bottomPhrase.scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
        logo.scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
      }
      isSyncingBottomScroll = false;
    }

    topPhrase.onscroll = function() {
      if (!isSyncingTopScroll) {
        isSyncingBottomScroll = true;
        isSyncingLogoScroll = true;
        bottomPhrase.scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
        logo.scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
      }
      isSyncingBottomScroll = false;
    }

    bottomPhrase.onscroll = function() {
      if (!isSyncingBottomScroll) {
        isSyncingTopScroll = true;
        isSyncingLogoScroll = true;
        topPhrase.scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
        logo.scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
      }
      isSyncingTopScroll = false;
    }

    logo.onscroll = function() {
      if (!isSyncingLogoScroll) {
        isSyncingTopScroll = true;
        isSyncingBottomScroll = true;
        topPhrase.scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
        bottomPhrase.scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
      }
      isSyncingLogoScroll = false;
    }

    allScroll.dispatchEvent(new Event('scroll'));

  </script>
```

So, when I scroll allScroll, the other objects should scroll. However, nothing happens and I' not getting any errors.

Ideas anyone?

Here's the HTML:

```
<section id="scroll-landing">
  <div id="scroll-display">
    <div id="we">Lorem</div>
    <div id="top-phrase">
      <ul id="top-phrase-scroll">
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>Lorem lorem lrem</li>
        <li>Lorem lorem lrem</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="logo">
      <div id="logo-display">
        Lorem lorem lrem
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom-phrase">
      <ul id="bottom-phrase-scroll">
        <li>Lorem lorem lrem</li>
        <li></li>
        <li class="hc">Lorem lorem lrem</li>
        <li class="sd">Lorem lorem lrem</li>
        <li class="ed">Lorem lorem lrem</li>
        <li class="dt">Lorem lorem lrem</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="design"></div>
    <div id="pop-out"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please add some cut down HTML that allows readers to [reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Lorum ipsum text is fine.

Comment: HTML added for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Dispatching an event is handled synchronously, so dispatching a "scroll" event on `allScroll` won't do anything because it (the `allScroll` object) doesn't have an event listener when the event is dispatched.

Try moving

```
allScroll.dispatchEvent(new Event('scroll'));
```

to the bottom of the code.

---

**Update**:

First an example of syncing the vertical scroll offsets of the top phrase, logo and bottom phrase:

```js
"use strict";
let synchedElements = [
    document.getElementById("top-phrase"),
    document.getElementById("logo"),
    document.getElementById("bottom-phrase")
];

function syncScroll( event) {
     let target = event.target;
     synchedElements.forEach( function ( element) {
         if( element != target) {
             element.scrollTop = target.scrollTop;
         }
      });
}
synchedElements.forEach( function( element) {
    element.addEventListener("scroll", syncScroll, false);
});

function scrollAll( scrollTop) {
    syncScroll( {target: {scrollTop}});
}
```

```css
#top-phrase, #logo, #bottom-phrase {
     border: thin solid grey;  /* testing */
     max-height: 3em;
     overflow-x: hidden;
     overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<section id="scroll-landing">
  <div id="scroll-display">
    <div id="we">Lorem</div>
    <div id="top-phrase">
      <ul id="top-phrase-scroll">
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>Lorem lorem lrem</li>
        <li>Lorem lorem lrem</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="logo">
      <div id="logo-display">
        Lorem lorem lrem
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom-phrase">
      <ul id="bottom-phrase-scroll">
        <li>Lorem lorem lrem</li>
        <li></li>
        <li class="hc">Lorem lorem lrem</li>
        <li class="sd">Lorem lorem lrem</li>
        <li class="ed">Lorem lorem lrem</li>
        <li class="dt">Lorem lorem lrem</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="design"></div>
    <div id="pop-out"></div>
  </div>
</section>
<hr>
<button type="button" onclick="scrollAll(0)">scrollAll(0)</button>
<button type="button" onclick="scrollAll(30)">scrollAll(30)</button>
```

Some things became clearer after writing the snippet:

- the scroll event is a notification event that does not convey by how much an element was scrolled.
- the scroll event does not bubble up the DOM from one element to another, excepting that scrolling the document `body` element does bubble up to `window`.
- If all elements initially have a `scrollTop` value of zero, dispatching a scroll event to `allScroll` in the posted code won't do anything in the initial state.
- Scroll events are dispatched quickly, and handling every one can really slow down display update. Please search Stack Overflow and the web for potential methods of throttling the number of events processed.

The code above was to see synchronized scrolling in action and is presented FYI in the hope that it helps - it may not (and probably doesn't) implement all of your requirements.

Comment: That's not working. I now understand what you are saying, but I'm not seeing it do anything and I'm not getting any errors. I'm going to edit the code to reflect what is should be.